# can't USB tether on RasPI

Tags: android, raspbian

I am using Raspbian and need to usb tether from tablet (Yarvik tab264). I am using app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mstream.e2t.
I can see the device easytether-tap, output of ip link:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000 link/ether b8:27:eb:30:34:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: easytether-tap: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 500
link/ether 02:00:54:74:68:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

However, `ping -I easytether-tap 8.8.8.8` does not work.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.117.1   0.0.0.0         UG    205    0        0 easytether-tap
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 eth0
192.168.117.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     205    0        0 easytether-tap
```

dmesg

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dmesg|tail -n 20
[   30.854092] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[   30.854319] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[   31.244505] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
[   31.244547] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0,   SerialNumber=0
[   31.245844] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[   31.246022] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[   31.524094] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[   31.624454] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[   31.624496] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0,  SerialNumber=0
[   31.627743] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[   31.699219] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at     usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:30:34:50
[   31.794171] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[   31.894936] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=0007
[   31.894976] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3,     SerialNumber=4
[   31.894994] usb 1-1.3: Product: Android
[   31.895014] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: USB Developer
[   31.895031] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 20080411413fc082
[   32.750603] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   34.173661] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[   37.598492] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:2 across:2134012k SSFS
```

Comment: `ping 4.4.4.4` does not work for me on a normal internet connection. Are you sure you don't mean `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`?

Comment: You are right, I mean `ping 8.8.8.8`, but still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I communicated with developer. This app does not pass through ICMP. In fact it allows just HTTP(S).